# VWD 2008 Adding reference to a public class

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, class, reference, visual-web-developer

Problems started after upgrading from VWD2005 to VWD2008.
In VWD2008 the App_Code does not exist any more.

How can i add a reference to a class that existed in the App_Code directory of VWD2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here comes the Global application class also know as Global.asax

All i had to do is add it to my project.

Answer (score 0):

VWD2008 supports web applications as well as web sites.

Web Applications do not have an app_code folder.

Check your project type, You probably have a Web Application instead of a Web Site. You can recreate it as a web site or alternatively just add a folder called code or whatever.

**EDIT:** In a Web Site there is only one default namespace and any code in the app_code folder is accessible everywhere. In a Web Application the code in a folder has a different namespace and therefore must be referenced by its namespace or by adding a using at the top of the file.

Comment: I don't mind about the app_code directory. I was disturbed that could not "see" any functions i had in a class within it. Thank you.